# Sous vide timing for prime rib

Tags: beef, temperature, sous-vide

I'm looking to sous vide a boneless, 6 lb rib roast, for New Year's Eve.  If I set the temp for 136F, how long should I leave this to cook?

My thought was 6 hours, but that's just based on experience and not any actual calculations.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with experience being your guide.

Comment: No, just a little uneasy ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surveying the top search results for [sous vide prime rib](https://www.google.com/search?q=sous+vide+prime+rib&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS438US438&oq=sous+vide+prime+rib), the consensus appears to be about 7 hours, with some leeway on either side.

- [Cooking Sous vide](http://www.cookingsousvide.com/info/sous-vide-recipes/more/sous-vide-prime-rib-roast-recipe) - 5-10 hours at 137 F.
- [Big Wayner BBQ](http://www.bigwaynerbbq.com/2013/10/03/my-take-on-the-perfect-sandwich-sous-vide-prime-rib/) - 7 hours at 135 F.
- [Modernist Cuisine](http://www.modernistcookingmadeeasy.com/tags/sous-vide-prime-rib-recipes) - 5-10 hours at 137 F.
- [Cave Man Keto](http://cavemanketo.com/2013/02/09/perfect-prime-rib/) - 10 hours at 136.5 F
- [Sous Vide Recipes](http://www.sousviderecipes.net/beef/sous-vide-prime-rib) - range of temperatures depending on desired donenness, "couple hours"

Note that you don't want to hold prime rib for extended periods (such as overnight) in its bath, as enzymatic action will make it mushy.

Comment: Yes, extended hours what I was afraid of too, I really don't want to over do it.  Since this is my first, I'll probably probe it when I pull it out to make sure the temperature is safe in the middle.  Thank you for the references!

Comment: I edited back to F, which is what's explicitly stated in all those links (except one) so it's pretty clear it's what's meant. It's not actually dangerous; the cooking *time* matters too, not just the temperature, and [135F is safe for beef up to 6.5-7cm thick](http://www.douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html#Table_5.1).